# accessing a service from an entity

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have the following code that I put inside an entity class:

```
$filesystem = $this->container->get('knp_gaufrette.filesystem_map')->get('amazon');
$filesystem->write($this->file , $this->name, true);
```

However, this always generate an error of:

```
Notice: Undefined property: MySite\UserBundle\Entity\ProfilePicture::$container in /Users/Mike/Sites/MySite/src/MySite/MainBundle/Entity/Document.php line 98
```

Any idea why this is the case? How do I access a service container from an entity?

I've put this inside an abstract class:

```
abstract class Document
{

......
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a legacy environment i've created a doctrine eventlistener that inject automatically the container in a entity that implements ContainerAwareInterface. With it i can work with some "legacy entity" with the minimum effort.

It's like how [Symfony ControllerResolver](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php) injects the container in a controller  but for entity.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


/**
 * adds some nice features to more easy entity utilization
 *
 * @DI\Service
 * @DI\Tag("doctrine.event_listener", attributes = {"event" = "postLoad"})
 */
class ContainerAwareListener extends ContainerAware
{

    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *     "container" = @DI\Inject("service_container"),
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container = null){
        $this->setContainer($container);
    }

    /**
     * After object is loaded, listener inject the container
     *
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if($entity instanceof ContainerAwareInterface){
            $entity->setContainer($this->container);
        }
    }
}
```

the entity need to implement the containerawareinterface and the required services can be obtained in setContainer() method, the service is defined with [JMSDIExtrabundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle) but can be defined under services.yml .

As many suggest this is a bad practice because the entity must depend as little as possible from all. But as a extrema ratio (or under extreme deadlines:-) ) this is great.

Comment: have you ever thought of using Entity listener?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean, it's an entity listener:)

Answer (score 0):

Entities are data models and should contain only data.

Instead, create a listener or manager service with dependency injection.

Comment: Is a good advice, but it's a bit skinny. Please, provide to OP more info and code :)

Comment: @akluth the thing is that this Document class has a method called performUpload() and inside this method is where I actually do the uploads